# Modelling multiple-choice question and correct answer in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm defining a simple one-to-many relationship in SQLA 1.3:

```
class Question(Base):
    """ Quiz questions """

    __tablename__ = "question"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_text = Column(Unicode(250), index=True)
    answers = relationship("Answer", back_populates="question")


class Answer(Base):
    """ Answers to quiz questions """

    __tablename__ = "answer"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("question.id"))
    answer_text = Column(Unicode(250), index=True)
    question = relationship("Question", back_populates="answers")
```

But I'd also like to specify which one of the answers is *correct*. I can't add e.g. an `answer_id` foreign key and `correct_answer = relationship("Answer", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[answer_id])` to `Question`, because that raises an `AmbiguousForeignKeysError`. Is there some other way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a correct answer intersection table, such as

```
class CorrectAnswer(Base):
    """ Correct answer to quiz questions """

    __tablename__ = "correct_answer"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("question.id"))
    answer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("answer.id"))
    question = relationship("Question", back_populates="correct_answer")
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("question_id", "answer_id"),)
```

The constraint is if you want to assume that every question has at most one correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a simple correct_answer_flag column to Answer table and mark 'Y' or 'N' for every correctly answered question.

Comment: Fair question, but I'd like to re-use answers among questions!

Comment: Add a FK answer_id (Non-Identifying) column to Question table.